# Issue implementing the python code around cx_Oracle library

Tags: python, pandas, oracle

I am getting an error while implementing the below code:
'''
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import sys

```
class IFTDataCore:
    def __init__(self, accountCode):
            i = 0
            all_Procedures = []
            dns_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn("gbhenora06vd.corp.amvescap.net", "1525", "INVU")
            db=cx_Oracle.connect("CORP-SVC-IFT", "C$Rp$vc1ftUat",dns_tns)
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select procedure_name from all_procedures where object_name = 'PK_IVZ_IFT_EXTRACT' ")
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            procedureName = ['PK_IVZ_IFT_EXTRACT.'+str(list(rows[indexRow])[0]) for indexRow in range(0,len(list(rows)))]
            l_cur = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)
            while i < len(procedureName):
                if procedureName[i] == 'PK_IVZ_IFT_EXTRACT.SP_IVZ_IFT_EXTRACT_ACCOUNTS':   
                    ret_cursor  = cursor.callproc(procedureName[i],(l_cur,))
                    dfx = pd.DataFrame(ret_cursor[0])  
                    all_Procedures.append(dfx)
                else:
                    ret_cursor  = cursor.callproc(procedureName[i],(l_cur,accountCode))
                    dfx = pd.DataFrame(ret_cursor[0])  
                    all_Procedures.append(dfx)
            i += 1
            self.all_Procedures = all_Procedures
            cursor.close()
            db.close()

    @property
    def getallProcedures(self):
        return self.all_Procedures

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Procedures = []
    all_Proc  = IFTDataCore('TOUHI')
    Procedures = all_Proc.getallProcedures()
    print(Procedures[0])
```

PS: The code works fine if I do not put the logic in **init** and call the def logic directly in code. Please let me know the possible reason why when class initialization is done in **main**, the definition starts throwing error.

Comment: Trace tells you exact problem: your statement contains invalid syntax, so you need to debug your code and examine the statement contained in `procedureName`

Comment: @astentx: I have corrected the code again and it is running error free when called directly as function definition, but did not generate any result when called from main

Comment: I do not see any significant change in your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68149699/revisions). You have to debug your code by yourself, we cannot do this for you. As of now it has no any entry point to tell you even *possible* reason

Answer (score 0):

The solution works fine now as per the below code:

```
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import sys
import json

from pathlib import Path
import os

class IFTDataCore:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            db = cx_Oracle.connect('invest/invest@INVD.WORLD')
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select procedure_name from all_procedures where object_name = 'PK_IVZ_IFT_EXTRACT' ")
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            procedureName = ['PK_IVZ_IFT_EXTRACT.'+str(list(rows[indexRow])[0]) for indexRow in range(0,len(list(rows))-1)]

            # To convert Accounts procedure to JSON format
            l_cur_Account = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)
            ret_cursor_Account  = cursor.callproc(procedureName[1],(l_cur_Account,))
            self.dfx_Account = pd.DataFrame(ret_cursor_Account[0])
            self.dfx_Account.columns = ['fundCode', 'fundName', 'legalEntitiyIdentifier','isin']
            result_Account = self.dfx_Account.to_json(orient='records')
        except BaseException as e:

            raise


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    positional_data = IFTDataCore()
    df_acct = positional_data.dfx_Account
    df_acct=df_acct.fillna("")
    Json=df_acct.to_json(orient='records')
    lambda_response = __lambda_response__('200', Json)
    
    return lambda_response

def __lambda_response__(status_code, response_body):
    return {
        'statusCode': status_code,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,GET'
        },
        'body': response_body
    }
```

Comment: If it looks good, then please mark it as solution and close the same